# What is the purpose of () in void main()?

Tags: flutter, dart

There is that () at the start of every void main. I am very new to flutter and trying to recognize all I am looking at, I guess this is a start. I'm watching a 5hr video on flutter and it hasn't mentioned it yet, I'm most of the way through it. Thanks!

Example (after "Main" and "Sunflower")

```
void main() {
  runApp(Sunflower());
}
```

Comment: *What is the purpose of () in void main()?* "this is a method without any params". Looks like you are new to programming in general as this syntax is present in almost every language present today.

Comment: That's two _different_ uses, for defining and then calling a [function](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#functions).

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly `()` is a part of a function, it is start and end of function parameters, it can use to call a function too.

Example 1: defining a function `print(String message) { }`

- **print** is *function name*.
- **String message** is *function parameter*.
- **()** will go right after *function name*, contains define *function parameter*, they have `String` type and `message` parameter name.

Example 2: calling a function `print(message)`:

- **print** is *function name*.
- **message** is value we put to **print** function as parameter.
- **()** will go right after *function name*, contains *function parameter*.